# How do I change the text in one area of my page when I hover over a link elsewhere on the same page?

Tags: css, hover

I'm fairly new to all this so please bear with me...

I'm designing a Web page for a class and I have a set of 5 pictures arranged to appear like a camera shutter. Each picture is a link to another page.
In the pentagon in the center there are to be the words, "Hover over an image to learn more," and when you hover over one of the shutter "slices," I want the text in the pentagon to change to a small description of the image being hovered over (rather than using mouseover text). Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Can be fixed quickly by using jQuery. Add your code to understand better

Comment: You can do this by giving the element you want to change an ID then change its text or HTML by JavaScript. Please add your code.

Comment: If you show us what you've tried, or what you have at the moment, we can look at a solution, you can hide and show elements on a page simply by using the hover class but we can't see your code so can't give you specific help

Comment: The answer, by the way, is yes, it can be done in CSS (rather than JavaScript, since you haven't tagged this with JavaScript). Something like `(your picture):hover ~ span::before {content: (your text here)}` or similar, depending on your setup.